# Google Goggles API For Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, google-goggles

I need to get the information at server-side from Image using Google Goggles.
Are there any available **Google Goggles API** for **Java**. I searched on Google but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It will be called Google Mirror API, but it has not been released yet. They just had their first Hackathon in NYC for Google Glass.